# Injecting singleton in guice module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have written some modules with guice. These are working great.
I have also some singletons or a logger I need in my modules which I want to inject into these modules.

For example I have my JpaModule where I need my Configuration.

**ConfigurationModule:**

```
@Singleton
public class ConfigurationModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(Configuration.class).toProvider(ConfigurationProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
  }
}
```

**JpaModule:**

```
public class JpaDaoModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Inject
  Configuration config;

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    // ... Read config and do something
  }
}
```

**Call to Guice:**

```
Guice.createInjector(new ConfigurationModule(), new JpaDaoModule());
```

How can I accomplish this? Or how can I provide the configuration to the JpaModule the guicy way?

/Kind regards

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. In the *configure()* method you set up your bindings. You cannot expect them to be available already. Also, modules are not eligible for injection per se. You can, however, get access to Guice-managed instances in providers or *@Provides* methods.

```
@Provides
@Named("myConfigItem")
String provideSomeConfigItem(Configuration config) {
    return config.get("myConfigItem");
}
```